# Ecmascript 6 Class: access constructor created method of super class

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor, ecmascript-6, overriding

I'm creating methods inside a constructor, to work with private values - this seems to be the suggested pattern to create private properties and limit the access to them.

Now I inherit from that class and within the constructor of the derived class I create another method, trying to access that. Unfortunately I get an exception `TypeError: ... is not a function`.

What to do? I can use the constructor as exactly that and just create a new object, but that would not be related to its classes and copying all the properties of the class and the super class etc. seems quite annoying and not like the right way. So again, what to do?

Here is an example:

```
 class ClassA {
constructor() {
        this.getValue = () => "private value";
    }
 }

 class ClassB extends ClassA {
constructor() {
   super();
       this.getValue = () => `${super.getValue()}, second private value`;
    }
 }

 const a = new ClassA();
 const b = new ClassB();

 console.log(`a.getValue = ${a.getValue()}`);
 console.log(`b.getValue = ${b.getValue()}`);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s70400ux/2/) Check the console. The outcome I'd expect is "private value, second private value".

If someone can give me a hint, or a not super shitty workaround, I'd appreciate that.

Thanks, fea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`super` refers to the classes `prototype`. As your methods are not prototype methods but instance methods, it will unfortunately not work. However you could store the original function reference in a variable:

```
 const orig = this.getValue.bind(this);
this.getValue = () => `${orig()}, second private value`;
```

---

However i personally rather like the `_` pattern:

```
 class ClassA {
    constructor() {
        this._private = "test";
    }
    getValue(){ return this._private; }
 }

class ClassB extends ClassA {
   constructor() {
      super();
   }

   getValue(){
     return `${super.getValue()}, second private value`;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution isn't really my choice because _private is not really private and you still expose it through the getter. But the first one really did it for me.